# Truffle upgradeable contracts: how pass a different owner from default? (transaction's parameter 'from')

Tags: truffle, openzeppelin

I used to deploy my contracts in my tests passing a specific account as owner:

```
const MyToken = artifacts.require("MyToken");
let erc20MyToken;

beforeEach(async function () {
   erc20MyToken = await MyToken.new({from: accounts[6]});
}
```

Now I'm trying to make this contract upgradeable making use of OpenZeppelin plugin, but when I try to pass the object with the transaction's parameter, I got 'Invalid number of parameters for "initialize". Got 1 expected 0!':

```
const MyToken = artifacts.require("MyToken");
let erc20MyToken;

beforeEach(async function () {
   erc20MyToken = await deployProxy(MyToken, [{from: accounts[6]}]);
}
```

How could I do it?

Regards,

**UPDATE 2022-03-19: Adding contract code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract MyToken is
    Initializable,
    ERC20Upgradeable,
    OwnableUpgradeable
{
    event TokenMinted(
        address indexed tokenBuyer,
        uint256 quantity,
        uint256 contractBalance
    );

    function initialize() external initializer {
        __ERC20_init("Soccer Bet Token", "SBT");
        __Ownable_init();
    }

    receive() external payable {
        _mint(msg.sender, msg.value);
        emit TokenMinted(msg.sender, msg.value, address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the contract you are trying to deploy?

Comment: Included in the question, @JulissaDC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are sending an array with the `account[6]` instead of just the `{from: accounts[6]}`, it gets solved if you do:

```
beforeEach(async function () {
   erc20MyToken = await deployProxy(MyToken, {from: accounts[6]});
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the second parameter is a array of unknown

Comment: It worked for me, are you passing accounts as a parameter?